# Is it possible to create/add shortcut on lockscreen instead of homescreen in iOS Devices?

Tags: ipad, shortcut, screen-lock

As I follow up this reference link:

[How do I create a link on the iPad home screen to a specific pdf?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68290/how-do-i-create-a-link-on-the-ipad-home-screen-to-a-specific-pdf/273971)

for a requirement, However my requirement is slightly different. I want to put the shortcut on lockscreen, So whenever user click on thier iPad home button, instead of opening the home screen after unlock the screen, user directly click on that shortcut and execute their process.

I tried to search this feature but didn't get any references, other than above mentioned.

Please sugesst.....

Comment: Are you indicating you want the user to go directly to your Shortcut instead the Home screen when unlocking?

Comment: @fsb Yes, I want something like that.....

Comment: I don't believe that's possible.  I won't put this as an answer because I'm not 100% sure it can't be done; hopefully someone with more info can provide a definitive answer or workaround.